# Java concurrent safe worker pool queue

Tags: spring, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am writing Spring (Java 8) web application and per each request(separate thread) my application make a few tasks, which should be completed as quickly as possible to return result to client in browser, so I'd like to find worker pool library, which can be accessed from different threads in safe way.

I have read about Execution pool, Rabbit MQ, but I couldn't find information about the feature of accessing the tasks queue from different threads.

I will really appreciate if somebody can give me advice how to do it in Java.

Comment: Have a look at [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async). Using this you would be able to spawn new threads and return response post their completion

Comment: Could you give a link about how to configure TaskExecutor in Spring (thread pool size , etc...) by using annotations?

Comment: [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) you go :)

Comment: So, It seems I have solved my problem by using @Async annotation and Spring ThreadPoolExecutor. Thanks again, please place below your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use asynchronous method call supported by Spring via [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) annotation.

The `@Async` annotated method will be executed in new thread and the result will be available in [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object (*`void` return is also supported*). Do note that the method call is *non-blocking* which will help return the response quickly without waiting for every task to complete. However if required the main thread can be made to wait for all task i.e. `Future` to complete via `Future.get()` which is blocking.

To configure the asynchronous support, annotate the configuration class with `@EnableAsync` and provide below method definition as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

```
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```